# What is the best way to save Presto Query Result to S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, amazon-emr, amazon-athena, presto

Our use case is that user queries data on S3 and we are using presto to query data on S3. The result should be saved in S3 as csv. csv size would be around 1gb and queries go up to 300 at a time. User is given an API to submit his query. Athena can't keep up with requests so we are trying to use presto instead.

Comment: **Side-question:** I'm an Athena user, so I'm interested in your comment that "Athena can't keep up with requests". Can you explain more about this? For example, what happens when it can't keep up -- does it return a particular error, or do the requests simply queue-up? Have you saved your data in an efficient format (eg Snappy, partitioned Parquet)?

Comment: We have saved our data in Parquet and it is partitioned. When we run a single query (joins four tables) it takes about 30 seconds to complete and generate a csv in S3 (750mb). So when we submit 100 queries (scheduled queries could be 300) to Athena most of them are rejected because our queuing capacity is about 60 so we use retry mechanism. Those 100 query takes 15 minute to finish. when those 100 queries are submitted and if someone other submits his query it gets queued we don't want that. we want to give the other person query priority to finish as fast as possible.Thanks for replying.

Comment: Thanks for the info -- I'm not hitting Athena with a large quantity like that. By the way, I highly recommend also using Snappy compression -- it reduces the cost of queries and might make them faster too.